# getters and setters between java and kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hi I have a got a piece of code that works strangly.

I have a setter and getter method which is in java

```
public void setCalcA(Float calcA) {
    this.calcA = calcA;
}

 public Float getCalcA() {
        return calcA;
    }
```

And I am trying to set it from Kotlin file like this, but it gives me a varied result, works correctly some times but not always set with the right value.
Setting the values work fine but when I try to access it it gives me wrong values.

```
val uplifted = upTot.notZeroOrNull() ?: upSTot
calcA = uplifted?.let { departureTotal?.minus(it) }
```

When I change it to the code bellow assigning the value to a variable then using `calculatedArrival = value` it works fine.

```
val uplifted = upTot.notZeroOrNull() ?: upSTot
val value = uplifted?.let { departureTotal?.minus(it) }
calcA = value
```

any ideas on why this is the case

Comment: Can you add some context around your code snippets?  For example, you reference `calcA` as if it's a local variable, but to call the `setCalcA` method on your Java object, I'd expect you to be doing `someObject.calcA = foo`.  It would help greatly if you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).